# Facebook Page or Group

Tags: social-media, marketing, facebook

Say I was hired by a store to put up Facebook account. Since I do not know who are the people that could be connected to the store, I put up a Facebook profile so I can add friends. This is against Facebook terms and conditions that only individual should put up a profile account. My strat is when I reach 300 friends, (network is built then) I then create a page where I will redirect everyone then delete the profile account. Is this ok?

Comment: This is exactly what Facebook pages are for, I'd recommend creating one ASAP and deleting the personal account once your fans have time to move over.

Comment: I don't really see a UX question in here. This is really just a question of how you should be using Facebook. As such, it really belongs on a Facebook support forum.

Answer (score 2):

You should either create a Facebook Page or a Facebook Group. Profiles are reserved for individual users and are best adapted for this purpose.

A Facebook Page is good if your company is mostly interested in broadcasting to a large group of fans and having as much control over the conversation as possible. This should be the ideal option for your client.

A Facebook Group is better suited for smaller communities where it's more about free discussion among the members than marketing per se. A major difference is that fans of a page only get notified when a new message is sent by the owner of the page, where as group members get notified of all new messages no matter who sent them.